# Case command executes but does not make any changes

Tags: mysql-workbench

I performed the command and it executed without any errors

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET LAST_NAME =
    CASE
        WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'Monika' THEN LAST_NAME = 'Arora'
        WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'Niharika' THEN LAST_NAME = 'Verma'
        WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'Vishal' THEN LAST_NAME = 'Singhal'
            WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'Amitabh' THEN LAST_NAME = 'Singh'
            WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'Vivek' THEN LAST_NAME = 'Bhati'
            WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'Vipul' THEN LAST_NAME = 'Diwan'
            WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'Satish' THEN LAST_NAME = 'Kumar'
            WHEN FIRST_NAME = 'Geetika' THEN LAST_NAME = 'Chauhan'
            ELSE LAST_NAME 
    END;
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

however, when I perform select * from... command, no change is made

I tried changing the equals sign to IS but that made no change. Please help!

Edit: FIRST_NAME is a column with names in it and LAST_NAME is a column which is completely NULL